# How to collect each Service name and its Status in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I want to fetch all service_name and its status without using any 3rd party tool. So far [SC](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) command was good enough to fetch one of the values, something like

```
sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME
```

but I also need `STATUS` for each `SERVICE_NAME` listed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a command that should do the job:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %s in ('sc query state^= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') do
    @(for /f "tokens=4" %t in ('sc query %s ^| find "STATE     "') do @echo %s is %t)
```

How it works:

First `sc query state= all | find "SERVICE_NAME"` is run. This command is designed to give you the service names, one per line. The carets `^` (which I have removed here) are necessary in order to escape the special characters that you want to affect the `sc` command and not the `for` command itself.

Then the initial `for /f` parses the above output to remove the standard "SERVICE_NAME:" prefix from each line, giving you pure service names. At this point the output looks like this:

```
C:\>for /f "tokens=2" %s in ('sc query state^= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') do @echo %s
AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc
AeLookupSvc
ALG
AppIDSvc
Appinfo
AppMgmt
aspnet_state
AudioEndpointBuilder
AudioSrv
```

This output is then fed to the next `for /f`, which runs `sc query servicename`, finds the line with the state, and isolates the 4th "word" (the current state).

Finally, the name of each service is printed along with its state (at this point you can choose to do something different if you wish).

**Important note:** If you run this inside a batch file, the percent signs (e.g. at `%s`) need to be doubled.

Comment: I found this did not return kernel drivers, but I found `sc query state=all type=all` returned everything I expected.

Answer (score 4):

By the way

```
sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME
```

will show only active (RUNNING) services, so there is no need to filter status (STATE).

Try SC with findstr syntax that supports multiple filtered items:

```
sc query state= all | findstr "SERVICE_NAME STATE"
```

or

```
sc query state= all | findstr "DISPLAY_NAME STATE"
```

or both

```
sc query state= all | findstr "SERVICE_NAME DISPLAY_NAME STATE"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Try Get-Service

PowerShell has [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service). It has a little less detail than sc.exe.

## Try SC.exe

```
sc.exe query state= all
```

(**Note:** `sc query state=all` will NOT work. You NEED the space sign after the equals sign. Otherwise you will get this weird error: `[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.`)

Source: https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html

Answer (score 1):

ss64.com/nt/sc.html

```
sc state= active¦inactive¦all
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) for the post, that was very helpful.  I wanted a column aligned output, so I grabbed your example above and created the following batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO.Service                                                  State
ECHO.-------------------------------------------------------  -------------

FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %%S IN ('sc query state^= all ^| FIND "SERVICE_NAME" ^| FIND /I "myservice"') DO (
    @(FOR /f "TOKENS=4" %%T IN ('sc query %%S ^| FIND "STATE     "') DO (
        SET OUTPUT="%%S -------------------------------------------------------------"
        @ECHO !OUTPUT:~1,55!^> %%T
    ))
)
ENDLOCAL
```

That produces an output suitable for what I was looking for like this:

```
Service                                                  State
-------------------------------------------------------  -------------
MyService.Test_1 --------------------------------------> STOPPED
MyService.Test_2 --------------------------------------> RUNNING
MyService.Test_3 --------------------------------------> STOPPED
```

Here's a breakdown of the relevant changes

- added the additional find to filter to only the service names I wanted to see instead of the whole list, in this case looking for service names that contain "myservice" `FIND /I "myservice"`
- Since it's in a batch file, changed `%s` and `%t` to `%%s` and `%%t` respectively (I like to use caps for vars)
- Added the `OUTPUT` var for formatting (`SET OUTPUT="%%S -------------------------------------------------------------"`), the value is quoted since I initially intended to use spaces, but switched to a dash `-`, that can be changed to any character you like, I considered `*` as well.  The value is set to the service name plus whatever padding character.
- The output line `@ECHO !OUTPUT:~1,55!^> %%T`

  - The formatted output: `!OUTPUT:~1,55!` uses `!` because of the delayed expansion and takes 55 characters starting at the 2nd character (zero based index) in order to remove the leading `"`
  - `^>`: the `^` escapes the `>` so it does not attempt to redirect to... somewhere. All in order to just include the `>` in the output line (totally not necessary)
  - Finally, `%%T`, the state output

Hope this helps someone! I can never remember this stuff!