# List of services in OS - golang

Tags: go, windows-services, operating-system

How can I get the list of currently installed services in golang under Windows?

I need something like:

[List of currently running process in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030680/list-of-currently-running-process-in-golang)

but for services and not process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all Windows service names starting with a common word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878921/how-to-get-all-windows-service-names-starting-with-a-common-word)

Comment: I am looking for implementation in go programming language

Comment: I'm aware of that requirement, but I guess you can [call shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7786922/2626313) from `go` and the shell command would look like shown in the linked answer, so I (wearing your shoes) would walk this way and considered the problem solved. You can of course wait until someone else shows up providing some better hint

Comment: Check if the [`syscall`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) or `golang.org/x/sys/windows` packages has anything to help you, otherwise you'll likely need/want to `os.exec` as previously mentioned.

Comment: @xmojmr  looks like will need to use os.exec - thanks for your help

Comment: @DaveC  looks like will need to use os.exec - thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such function in the standard library and there will likely never be.

Consider using [one of the functions in `os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) to launch a Windows program that will list the available services and parse its output (e.g. ["`sc query state=all`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172997/how-to-collect-each-service-name-and-its-status-in-windows)).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but figured I would share this link anyways.
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/mgr

This package provides an API for creating, controlling and listing windows services on both the local and remote systems.

I copied the following text from the above link:

```
func (m *Mgr) ListServices() ([]string, error)
```

ListServices enumerates services in the specified service control manager database m. If the caller does not have the `SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS` access right to a service, the service is silently omitted from the list of services returned.